# Capturing Json values from previous response and pass into subsequent request for dynamic count of variables

Tags: jmeter

I want to extract values from a json response of previous request and assign the values to variables and use them in subsequent request body.

**Request 1 Response**

[
{
"Specialization": "Computer Science",
"DegreeProviderId": "DegreeProvider:2eb78dd0-1422-785252d8f804",
"Type": "Update",
"GId": "Party:e5329b74-a88b-df59e1d7de9e",
"TeacherId": "TeacherProvider:7e7f5628-663f-42e1-a6e6-13cb0bd34e3d",
"UpdatedDate": "2021-05-31T13:07:21",
"FirstName": "Tibet",
"NewData": [
"SSN : 878-00-1250",
"FullName : "
],
"CollegeName": "TTT",
"LastName": "China",
"InProgress": true
},
{
"Specialization": "Agriculture Science",
"DegreeProviderId": "DegreeProvider:2eb78dd0-1422-7852u65f804",
"Type": "Update",
"GId": "Party:e5329b74-a88b-df7865rfdt-de9e",
"TeacherId": "TeacherProvider:7e7f5628-663f-42e1-a6e6-13cb0bd34e3d",
"UpdatedDate": "2021-05-31T13:07:21",
"FirstName": "Auf",
"NewData": [
"SSN : 548-00-9890",
"FullName : "
],
"CollegeName": "AAA",
"LastName": "Usa",
"InProgress": true
},

I have to pass value of DegreeProviderId in subsequent request like below

**Next Request body**

[{"Id":"DegreeProvider:2eb78dd0-1422-785252d8f804","IsValued":false,"Comment":""},
{"Id":"DegreeProvider:2eb78dd0-1422-7852u65f804","IsValued":false,"Comment":""},

Total number of records(DegreeProviderId) is not a constant, its changing continuously. Subsequent Request body size depends of count of records(DegreeProviderId) received in previous response. So I need to write a code to capture the values of DegreeProviderId values and use them in subsequent request. Please help me to face this challenge. Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def payload = []
   new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).each { entry ->
       payload.add([Id: entry.DegreeProviderId, IsValued: false, Comment: ''])
   }

   vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. That's it, the code will extract the `DegreeProviderId` values from the response no matter how may of them are there and construct the `${payload}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) holding these `DegreeProviderID` and other attributes

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)